# Auto align a image set in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

If in a powerpoint slide, I have a images set

```
img1 img2
img3 img4
```

How I can auto align this images in the slide ?

Comment: By auto-align, you mean you want them in a perfect square? Are they all the same size?

Comment: @Karan, yes perfect square, and yes they are the same size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

[image: 1]

**Option 2:**

1. Select any 2 images
2. Align / Align Bottom
3. Align / Distribute Horizontally
4. Select remaining 2 images
5. Align / Align Top
6. Align / Distribute Horizontally
7. Now select left two images
8. Align / Distribute Vertically
9. Finally select right two images
10. Align / Distribute Vertically

[image: 2]

I don't know if there's any faster method.